# Vue img with variable in src not shown

Tags: html, image, vue.js, vuejs3, src

i want to show a img based on the index of a vue list.

Code:

```
doesnt work    <img v-bind:src="`../cocktailpictures/` + (data.index) + `.jpeg`" />
works          <img src="../cocktailpictures/1.jpeg" />
```

vue data.index code in Browser:

```
<img src="../cocktailpictures/1.jpeg" data-v-c289a062="">
```

How to fix this? For me it seems all right, the src path get build correct.

Comment: try removing the brackets from (data.index) and see if it works.  :src="`../cocktailpictures/` + data.index + `.jpeg`"

Comment: the problem is the same. Is it possible, that the src path get build after HTML trys to load the picture? Like descriped is the src path in the browser correct, it looks to me like a more general vue process logic problem

Comment: <img :src="require(`../cocktailpictures/` + data.index + `.jpeg`)" /> fixes the problem!